# How to define platform-specific page elements for iOS and Android in a single place using QAF?

Tags: java, appium, qaf

I'm developing a test case that needs to run on both iOS and Android platforms using QAF (Qmetry Automation Framework). I want to follow a Page Object approach where I can define elements for both platforms in a single place and reuse them in my tests.

In Appium, I can achieve this by using annotations like @AndroidFindBy and @iOSXCUITFindBy. Here's an example:

```
@HowToUseLocators(androidAutomation = LocatorGroupStrategy.ALL_POSSIBLE, iOSXCUITAutomation = LocatorGroupStrategy.ALL_POSSIBLE)
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='merchant-name']")
@iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "Home")
protected WebElement home;
```

This allows me to specify different locators for Android and iOS, and the framework automatically chooses the appropriate locator based on the platform.

However, I couldn't find a similar implementation in QAF. Is there a way to achieve the same result in QAF? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this in QAF. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QAF has great capabilities of re-usability for cross platform test automation.
You should utilize  [locator repository](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locator_repository.html) feature of qaf to abstract locator out from the code. For example, if using page class,
instead of having platform specific class

```
IosHomePage.java


@iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "Home")
protected WebElement home;

AndriodHomePage.java

@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='merchant-name']")
protected WebElement home;
```

you can have single class with separate locator repository for each platform (android and ios in this case)

HomePage.java

```
@FindBy(locator = "home.ele.loc")
protected WebElement home;
```

you can create locator repository for each platform and add locator in it

```
resource
  - appilcation.properties
  -common
     - 
  - android
     - homescreen.properties
     - 
     - 
  -ios
     - homescreen.properties
     - 
     -
```

At the time of execution specify which resources you want to use by using `env.resources` property. For example, if want to run for android

```
env.resource=resource/common;resources/android
```

for android

```
env.resource=resource/common;resources/ios
```

Another alternate is [driver specific resources](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html#managing-driver-specific-resource). In that case your properties will look like below

```
env.resource=resource/common
android.resources=resources/android
ios.resources=resources/ios
```

Refer:

- [locator repository](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locator_repository.html)
- [managing resources](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html)
- [properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_configuration.html)
- [Repository editor](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/repo_editor.html)

There is also a good training material available from perfecto on [Locator & Capabilities](https://help.perfecto.io/perfecto-help/content/courses/module_2___locators___capabilities.htm)